# Regex to match Column Items in Dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the following DataFrame with only 1 column :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
                                            Mat Header    
0      TURBINE , GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25
```

I have written this regex which is only able to extract the first word :

```
str.extract(r'([A-Z]\w+)')
```

I have to extract all the words Turbine, gas, M\s hitachi, h-25. Please help

Comment: What about `str.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\S*')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mat Header':['TURBINE , GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25']})
df['Results'] = df['Mat Header'].str.findall(r'\b[A-Z]\S*\b').str.join(', ')
```

Output of `df['Results']`:

```
>>> df['Results']
0    TURBINE, GAS, MAKE, M/S, HITACHI, MODEL, H-25
Name: Results, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/obd3bx/1), it matches

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: I want this to be populated into different columns.                                                                  
**df[['item', '???', 'Make', 'Model', 'Type', 'Mounting', 'Governor Type', 'Compressor Model', 'Speed', 'Tag No.', 'Service']] = df['Mat Header'].str.findall(r'\b[A-Z\S*\b]')**                         

`
As you may notice, there are more columns than values mentioned in the question as some of the columns below have these values present. This is is giving me Error :
 **Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable**

Comment: @saimkhan This is not clear. Please add all relevant details to the question body. Add more strings you have and the expected result.